# The tag f:event is only available on facelets

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I'm trying to put this tag on my jsp page, but when it loads I get this error

```
The tag f:event is only available on facelets.
```

Here's my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Orders</title>
</head>
<f:event listener="#{controller.method}" type="preRenderView" />
<body>
<f:view>
...
```

here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    piccolaAzienda
    
        index.html
    
    
        Faces Servlet
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        1
    
    
        Faces Servlet
        /faces/*

and here's my faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
```

Comment: Try _upgrading to facelet mode_, it's better to use it with an `.xhtml` file.

Comment: Create a new facelet (`.xhtml`) in your webapp, then copy the page code without jsp taglibs.